# Doesn't call onStop and onStart after screen locked and unlocked android 2.3

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

Doesn't call method onStart after screen locked android 2.3, after unlocking called resume method. On the andoid 4.1.2 (Jelly Brain) it works fine.
Can i fixed it ? Or i must move my logic in method onResume/onPause ?

Answer (score 2):

The Methods *onStart* and *onStop* bound the visible lifetime of the Activity. If the Lockscreen does not hide your Activity, these Methods will not be called at all. If you have logic depending on different states use the foreground lifetime Methods *onResume* and *onPause* or observer techniques like BroadcastReceiver.

Also remember, that prior to Android Honeycomb the Application is killable after *onPause*, so that *onStop* might not get called at all.

Comment: I found only the method onPause() was called by screen off on Android 2.3 device.

Answer (score 0):

You can either move your code to onPause/onResume or you can also register a broadcast receiver to watch the screen on/off state.